# How to install software from Ubuntu Software

Tags: apt, 16.04, root

Actually I'm beginner at Ubuntu. Please help me to install VLC, Office and so many software. When I clicked install in Ubuntu software, then it was showing *waiting for install*.

When i opened terminal and trying there, then it was showing me some messages:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Sometimes it shows:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What is root? Need I go to root? Or how could I install all software successfully?

Comment: Run the terminal command with `sudo`, which gives you root (admin) access. Enter your password then (no \*\*\* or **···** will show up, it will be blank when you type, just type and hit enter). By the way, MS Office is not available for Ubuntu. Use Libreoffice

Comment: how to install skype sir ? @Bharadwaj Raju

Comment: actually its like same :( :(  so i copied error line cause i was closed terminal when posting my question sir . @karel

Comment: @AHMRayhanuzzamanRoky Please ask a new question for that

Comment: for skype have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Error Above.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission
denied) E: Unable to lock the administration directory 
(/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

It means you don't have root/administrative permissions to install software's.

To install a software like VLC from the terminal.
You can issue the following command with sudo

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

And it will then prompt you for your password.

so always use `sudo`.

and you can also read more about sudo command, by typing in your terminal.

```
man sudo
```